# Accessing file data before upload complete in php

Tags: php, http, ubuntu, post

I am currently uploading a file to my server via http. All is well with the upload but I wanted to know if there is a way to access the data of an upload in the `$_FILES` global before the upload has completed so I can open another stream to a server and push the data over as it comes in

Previously in java I have had read and write streams open at once rather than reading then writing (working with parsing flat files)and this has dramatically increased the speed, so I guess I'm searching for a PHP equivalent for file uploads. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

May be this would give you a path to explore.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Check FileReader.readAsDataURL() section specially. Mostly when image upload needs a **preview before uploading**, **FileReader** object is used. Search for it you may get an idea